# Сгруппировать в SQL запросе поля по имени персонажа и вывести только записи с минимальной датой. Как сделать?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Есть таблица

```
name, date, price
Слон, 21-06-2021, 5000
Слон, 22-06-2021, 7500
Мартышка, 21-06-2021, 4000
Мартышка, 22-06-2021, 3900
Кот, 21-06-2021, 11200
Кот, 22-06-2021, 8700
```

Нужно сгруппировать по имени персонажа и вывести поле суммы с минимальной для персонажа даты, чтобы получилось:

```
Слон, 21-06-2021, 5000
Мартышка, 21-06-2021, 4000
Кот, 21-06-2021, 11200
```

Пробовал в HAVING написать условие min(date) = date и не получилось так сделать. Как получить нужный результат?

Comment: Нумерация в CTE. Для старой версии - подзапрос на получение минимальной даты либо его аналог (WHERE NOT EXISTS или LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL).

Comment: Под нумерацией имеете ввиду упорядочить по дате а потом получить по номер строки = 1? А как номер строки тогда получить?

Comment: Под нумерацией я разумею функцию ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Видимо MySQL версия старая стоит: Ответ MySQL: Документация
#1305 - FUNCTION row_number does not exist, а можнь ли выполнить нужный запрос используя group by, havving и функцию min применяемую к дате?

Comment: нет, в mysql так нельзя. при группировке исходных строк вообще не остается, так что показывать будет нечего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.name = t2.name
                     AND t1.`date` < t2.`date` )
```